# How to count number of people in submission SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I don't know how to count the number of people in submission and to output their list.

Employees.ReportsTo indicates id, that to whom this person submits.

```
Select
   Employees.LastName,
   Employees.FirstName,
   Region.RegionDescription,
   count(case 
         when Employees.ReportsTo=Employees.EmployeeID then 1 
         end) as Count_of_employees,
   Subordinates = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Employees.LastName 
                         FROM Employees
                         WHERE Employees.ReportsTo = Employees.EmployeeID
                         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')  
from
   Employees  
left join
   EmployeeTerritories 
      on  Employees.EmployeeID=EmployeeTerritories.EmployeeID  
left join
   Territories 
      on  EmployeeTerritories.TerritoryID=Territories.TerritoryID  
left join
   Region 
      on Territories.RegionID=Region.RegionID  
group by
   Region.RegionDescription,
   Employees.LastName,
   Employees.FirstName
```

That's in output:

```
Last name  First Name     RegionDescription  Count_of_employees Subordinates 
Davolio    Nancy          Eastern              0                NULL
Fuller     Andrew         Eastern              0                NULL
Peacock    Margaret       Eastern              0                NULL
Buchanan   Steven         Eastern              0                NULL
```

Here that has to be:

```
Last name  First Name     RegionDescription  Count_of_employees Subordinates 
Davolio    Nancy          Eastern              0                NULL
Fuller     Andrew         Eastern              3        Davolio,Peacock, Buchanan      
Peacock    Margaret       Eastern              0                NULL
Buchanan   Steven         Eastern              0                NULL
```

Sample data from Employees

```
FirstName   LastName    EmployeeID  ReportsTo
Nancy       Davolio     1           2
Andrew      Fuller      2           NULL
Janet       Leverling   3           2
Margaret    Peacock     4           2
Steven      Buchanan    5           2
Michael     Suyama      6           5
Robert      King        7           5
Laura       Callahan    8           2
Anne        Dodsworth   9           5
```

Comment: Please provide details on what does your query outputs and what is your expected result

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant tables DDL and some sample data as DML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is you are comparing fields only on the same row. Because `Employees` does not have an alias, SQL server doesn't know to compare the `Emploees.ReportsTo` in the inner select to the `Employees.EmployeeID` in the main select - it all looks the same. Try change Subordinates to:

```
Subordinates = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Employees.LastName 
                     FROM Employees ESubordinate -- so SQL knows it's a "different" table
                     WHERE ESubordinate.ReportsTo = Employees.EmployeeID
                     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

Also, don't use a `CASE` for the `COUNT` for a similare reason. Use another inner select:

```
 -- the () are important here, and ECount differentiates the two Employees tables too
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Employees ECount WHERE ECount.ReportsTo = Employees.ReportsTo) as Count_of_employees,
```

That should solve your problem. Bear in mind it's not the fastest. If you want speed, look into `CROSS APPLY`